# Make the first letter uppercase inside a django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am pulling a name from a database which is stored as `myname`. How do I display this inside a Django template as `Myname`, with the first letter being in uppercase.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

Using Django built-in template filter called [title](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#title)

```
{{ "myname"|title }}
```

Comment: It works for single-word strings. But, if you have a multi-words string, it's going to upper the first letter of each single word, instead of the first letter of the string.

Comment: It is howerver not useful with apostrophes like "My friend's house" or "you're an uppercase freak" which becomes "Friend'S" and 'You\'Re'.

Comment: This answer is wrong. |title does not make the first letter of a string uppercase. It makes first letter of each word uppercase. Example, "hello world" does not become "Hello world". It becomes "Hello World".

Comment: Use {{ obj | capfirst }} to make uppercase the first character only. Using {{ obj | title }} makes it Camel Case.

Comment: Since it's a string, you can also use the string's method `capitalize()` like this `{{ myname.capitalize }}`

Comment: works with jinja as well

Answer (score 188):

I know it's a bit late, but you can use [capfirst](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#capfirst):

```
{{ "waiting for action"|capfirst }}
```

This will result into "Waiting for action"

Comment: This is the correct answer if you just want the first letter capitalized.

Comment: This will ensure the first character is uppercase, but won't ensure the rest of  the string is lowercase. e.g. "hello World" would become "Hello World", not "Hello world". Which is sometimes fine, but not always :)

Comment: Yes, but this is not relevant to the question of the topic starter. Additional filters must be applied to handle extra logic. For example, @bjorn-garcia provides a solution for ensuring only the first word is capitalized.

Answer (score 34):

This solution also works if you have multiple words (for example all caps):

```
{{ "ALL CAPS SENTENCE"|lower|capfirst }}
```

This will output "All caps sentence".

Answer (score 8):

The `title` filter works fine, but if you have a many-words string like: `"some random text"`, the result is going to be `"Some Random Text"`. If what you really want is to uppercase **only** the first letter of the whole string, you should create your own custom filter.

You could create a filter like this (follow the instructions on how to create a custom template filter from this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) - it's quite simple):

```
# yourapp/templatetags/my_filters.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def upfirstletter(value):
    first = value[0] if len(value) > 0 else ''
    remaining = value[1:] if len(value) > 1 else ''
    return first.upper() + remaining
```

Then, you should load the my_filters file at your template, and use the filter defined there:

```
{% load my_filters %}

...
{{ myname|upfirstletter }}
```

Comment: downvote - duplicates existing functionality of `|capfirst`

Comment: You can see the implementation of the django defaults here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me in template variable.

```
{{ user.username|title }}
```

If the user is "al hasib" then the it will return "Al Hasib"

or

```
{{ user.username|capfirst }}
```

If user is 'hasib' then the last one will return "Hasib"

Both look something like same but there's some differences.

Answer (score 5):

use
`{{"myname"|title}}`
this will make the fist letter of each word capital

Answer (score 2):

Just use `{{myname | capfirst}}`
In Django the template filter *capfirst* capatialize the first letter of a given string.